# Change Template Latex to English

Tags: packages, overleaf, languages, babel-french, english

I am using this template to write my project report: https://github.com/stoufa/ISI-LaTeX-Template

It's in French by default: How can I change it to English? I want `Chapter 1` instead of `chapitre 1` and `Table` instead of `Tableau`…

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

To help you find the location of the line to change:

1. Look at the main document file `main.tex`, defined as the file containing the `\documentclass` command.
2. Line 18, it calls the content of another file called `new_commands.tex` contained in a folder called `tpl`.
3. Go to this folder and open this file. Choose between line 102 and line 103 to select the language you want.

Since I'm not familiar with this class, I can't guarantee that everything will work smoothly, but it looks fine.

*If I may, this class is fairly complex and you seem to just be discovering LaTeX. Do you really need to use this class?*

Comment: yes I  change to \selectlanguage{english} but nothing happen it still at french

Comment: I looked at a few others files for this class. A lot of strings are hard-coded to French, so I'm not sure this class can easily be used for another language. If you're really sure you need this class, you should contact the author (his address is on the Git repo you linked) and ask him directly.